# File not found exception while reading .js file within jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am facing a weird issue here. In my jenkins job I've configured it to pull my project's source code from artifacts. So I get 2 directories in workspace called classes and resources. Now some of my tests are failing with FileNotFoundException, stating ABCD.js not found in the given path. When I check this path in the jenkins workspace, this file exists there.
I am not sure about the problem. However, there are following tasks which I've added in the build steps.
1. Download the jar from the artifacts.
2. Unjar the downloaded jar in workspace.
3. Run the tests in the workspace.

Comment: Strange thing is, that I've 2 files in the same package 1 is a spring xml and another is ABCD.js. The test can read the .xml file but not the .js file.